# What is Ethash4G? Is it related to Ethash?

Tags: hash-algorithm

I've been toying around with the online crypto calculators, and stumbled across this on WhatToMine.

What is Ethash4G? Is it related to Ethash in anyway, and by extension, Ethereum?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ethash4g is basically ethash, but the DAG size limited to 4G so old GPU with 4G memory can mine ETH, since it's impossible now with standard ETHash because of the DAG size

Comment: Interesting. How do you know this? Do you have a source by any chance?

Comment: you can visit this for reference
https://github.com/todxx/teamredminer/blob/master/doc/ETHASH_4GB_HOWTO.txt

Comment: You sir, are awesome. Thanks for posting the link to Git. Have an upvote :)

Comment: When will Ether become un-minable through the Hash4g algorithm? Is there a timetable similar to the DAG for ETHASH?

Comment: @GipsyD you're welcome and thanks for the upvote :)

Comment: @Spellbinder2050 you can find the time table here : https://minerstat.com/dag-size-calculator 
and for ethash become "unminable" by 4GB GPU card, i think it will still be mineable until some times, if you see my earlier github link, there's explanation that the efficiency will drop based on DAG size.
current loss is about 20% drop of hashrate, so maybe by the end of this year, eth will be unminable by 4GB GPU
it's only my opinion tho.