# Dual mining ETH/ZIL with 4GB?

Tags: mining, mining-pools

I recently saw [this video](https://youtu.be/83KU1AE2kN0) about dual mining of ETH and ZIL. The video especially targets GPUs with 3-4GB of VRAM. I still have to try it, but I'm wondering: isn't ETH dagger size bigger than 4GB? How is it possible to mine it with GPUs of 3-4GB? I know about the Zombie mining but I read it will give decent results only for a very short time now. Is this the case?

Answer (score 1):

The DAG size is above 4GB, but you can use a modified PoW algorithm called `Ethash4G` that specifically targets older hardware.

See [this](https://github.com/todxx/teamredminer/blob/master/doc/ETHASH_4GB_HOWTO.txt) GitHub repository for more information.

See also: [What is Ethash4G? Is it related to Ethash?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/93010/what-is-ethash4g-is-it-related-to-ethash)